# How to solve error: InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects when mapping a dataframe to another one

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have a `Pandas DataFrame`. I am trying to map the `ProductID` from one `dataframe` to another `dataframe`.

Here is my attempt:

```py
Product_id_mapper = dict(df1[['ProductID', 'Cost']].drop_duplicates().values)

df2["Actual_cost"] = df2['ProductID'].map(Product_id_mapper)
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error:

```
InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
```

I wonder why I keep getting this error even after dropping duplicates

Comment: Can you provide an example which I can run and get the error?

Comment: Yes, I would love to, but a sample data does not help, because its a very large data frame and it is possible one small row that has the issue. So with a sample data, it would be much easier to fix the problem than actually diagnosing the problem if you have experience with it

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood correctly you want to merge based on a `Key` two dataframes. Then this is my suggestion:

Suppose `a.csv`:

```
carrier,type,count
DTH,a,123
DTH,b,3123
DTH,c,41341
DTH,d,13411
BLUEDART,a,12123
BLUEDART,b,31231
BLUEDART,c,411
BLUEDART,d,11
```

And `b.csv` is:

```
carrier,year
DTH,1997
BLUEDART,2005
```

Python code:

```
import pandas as pd

a_df = pd.read_csv(r"a.csv")
b_df = pd.read_csv(r"b.csv")

merged_df = pd.merge(a_df, b_df, on=['carrier'])
print(merged_df)
```

and the output:

```
    carrier type  count  year
0       DTH    a    123  1997
1       DTH    b   3123  1997
2       DTH    c  41341  1997
3       DTH    d  13411  1997
4  BLUEDART    a  12123  2005
5  BLUEDART    b  31231  2005
6  BLUEDART    c    411  2005
7  BLUEDART    d     11  2005
```

If `Key` column name is called differently on the CSVs, use:

```
out = (df1.merge(df2, left_on='key1', right_on='key2')
          .reindex(columns=[...]))
```